Problem with Matrix Represenations
How can I simplify this matrix (remove some of the dots and coefficients) while maintaining clarity and amount of information for the reader?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
Let \[A=\left|
\begin{array}{cccc}
a_0 & a_1 & \cdots & a_{2^k-1}\\
a_{2^k} & a_{2^k+1} & \cdots &a_{2^{k+1}-1}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_{\frac{4^k}{2}-2^k} & a_{\frac{4^k}{2}-2^k+1} & \cdots & a_{\frac{4^k}{2}-1}\\
b_0 & b_1 & \cdots & b_{2^k-1}\\
b_{2^k} & b_{2^k+1} & \cdots &b_{2^{k+1}-1}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
b_{\frac{4^k}{2}-2^k} & b_{\frac{4^k}{2}-2^k+1} & \cdots & b_{\frac{4^k}{2}-1}\\
\end{array}
\right|\]
Let
\[\displaystyle P(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{2^{2k-1}-1}a_nx^n, Q(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{2^{2k-1}-1}b_nx^n,
f(x)=\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}\] If $k\in\mathbb{N},$

Does\[\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=\frac{A}{Q(x)}?\]

\end{document}


If this is the very first time you're introducing this determinant to a reader, you may want to consider defining all the important parts bit by bit through prose, rather than cramming every element into a matrix. As it is now, you have superscripts and stacked fractions in your subscripts, which make it challenging to read.

How can I modify this question to make it easier to read? Also, thank you for your timely contribution

Also, to clarify your question, when you're asking for help with "simplifying," are you asking about how to simplify your idea mathematically (might be better for a different site), or how to simplify its appearance (TeX)?

I want to simplify the dots and coefficient terms in the matrix. Is that an appropriate ask for this site in particular, or would it be more beneficial if I were to move to a different, say, Math Stackexchange?

For Math SE, I am not well-versed in the rules of other StackExchange sites, so I'm not sure. For your question, I'd mostly suggest elucidating each part in prose, rather than putting everything into a single sentence. For instance, you could start with "Let k be natural number, and a_n and b_n be sequences of real numbers..." Furthermore, you could define A as the matrix in the top half your determinant, and define B as the bottom half. This way, you could replace the very large determinant with just A\\B because you've already defined them elsewhere.

That appears to be very intuitive. Thank you for your answer; I will use that formatting in my project. Thank you

Does the current edited version look better?

Something like this?

The main changes are (a) writing 4^k\!/2 instead of \frac{4^k}{2}, (b) use of a vmatrix environment instead of \left| \begin{array} ... \end{array} \right|, and (c) use of \mathclap in the middle displayed math row.
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\mathclap' macro; load 'amsmath' automatically
\usepackage{amssymb}   % for '\mathbb' macro.

\begin{document}

\noindent
For $k\in\mathbb{N}$, let $A$ be the determinant of a $2^k\times 2^k$ matrix:
\[
A=\begin{vmatrix}
a_0 & a_1 & \cdots & a_{2^k-1}\\
a_{2^k} & a_{2^k+1} & \cdots &a_{2^{k+1}-1}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
a_{4^k\!/2-2^k} & a_{4^k\!/2-2^k+1} & \cdots & a_{4^k\!/2-1}\\[1.5\jot]
b_0 & b_1 & \cdots & b_{2^k-1}\\
b_{2^k} & b_{2^k+1} & \cdots &b_{2^{k+1}-1}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
b_{4^k\!/2-2^k} & b_{4^k\!/2-2^k+1} & \cdots & b_{4^k\!/2-1}
\end{vmatrix}\,.
\]
Put
\[
P(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\mathclap{2^{2k-1}-1}} a_nx^n, \quad 
Q(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\mathclap{2^{2k-1}-1}} b_nx^n, \quad\text{and }
f(x)=\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}\,.
\] 
Does
\[
\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=\frac{A}{Q(x)}
\]
hold?
\end{document}

